# Vue js - the easiest way to integrate a html bootstrap template inside a vue project

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm currently working on a project using Laravel and Vuejs , I found a perfect template to use ( http://html.codedthemes.com/gradient-able/default/ ) the problem is that there is only a simple html version that includes bootstrap, jquery, smoothscroll ... and another version that is made for angular projects, so my question is, is there a simple way to integrate the simple html version with my Vue project ? or should I choose another template that supports Vuejs ?

Comment: Just split out the bits in to smaller, reusable and manageable components, use the general layout as a master template and just add in your vue bits as needed.

Comment: But what about Jquery doesn't make a confilict with Vue ??

Comment: You can use both JQuery and VueJS together, not sure why you'd need to but you can if it makes your life easier.

Comment: No i don't wan to use it but the template already has jquery with bootstrap

Comment: So remove the jquery bits and re-write it using Vue/ES6 or however makes you comfortable.